# my instance is getting billed even after buying a reserved instance (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-billing, aws-reserved-instances

Thanks for looking into this

I have purchased 2 reserved instance on AWS t3a.xlarge + windows and t3a.xlarge + windows + ms SQL for one year with no upfront as the payment method and region as Mumbai(ap-south)

Post the purchase I have launched the 2 instances in the same region with the same configuration AS I checked a day later I was getting billed for those new servers-where the reserved instance was not used.

How should I proceed here?? and where did I made the mistake
thanks in advance

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/apply_ri.html This may help

Comment: You should contact AWS Customer Service (which is _different_ to AWS Customer Support). They are very good at investigating and explaining such issues. These days, Savings Plans are potentially a better choice than Reserved Instances since they offer more flexibility.

Comment: can you give more information? What's the hourly usage? Are you talking about the no upfront fees that are at the first of the month each month? are you sure you purchased the right offering?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to look at this is through the AWS Cost Management service (Billing). In there you'll find the utilization dashboard and the coverage dashboard of your Reserved instances. That should give you a good idea why the RIs weren't applied.

Because there is a lot of missing information from your question, I'd suggest to check the following:

1. Regional vs AZ RIs - make sure that you didn't purchase RIs for a specific AZ and then deployed in in a different one (even if the region is the same)
2. See your hourly usage patterns. It's not attached to an instance, and calculated on a hourly basis.
3. Check carefully that the RIs you purchased are aligned with exactly what you deployed as you talked about a Windows machine which has several different offerings.

Good luck!